# Should I use OOP?

Tags: c++, c, class

I am a long time participant in a competition called [Robocup Rescue Line](http://rcj.robocup.org/rcj2016/rescue_line_2016.pdf). For next year's competition, I am building a robot (and the code for the robot) from the ground up. The tasks that the robot has to do are complex enough for the code to be a fairly complex thing. I have some experience with classes and OOP so I thought I could try to organize the code in a OOP fashion. I thought I could have a class for each type of Sensor (e.g: LineSensor(), RGBSensor UltraSound()...) and another for the Motors (e.g: Motor()) that would have two instances on the code. Basically, all the code has to do is take sensor readings and produce a motor response. With this class structure, where would I do this correspondence? Is this not appropriate for this kind of project? Is there a better way to do this, that is still OOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a lot of experience with OOP, but mostly in embedded/pure software designs. However, I'm sure you can use it in a robot project too.

Avoid creating lots of objects dynamically, this results in gap in the very small memory available for the Uno. Try to create the object instances beforehand (this will also benefit performance hits during execution, by placing it into the initialization).

About the Sensors: you can make a baseclass if needed (Sensor) and let other classes derive from it (there is a small performance hit when calling methods though).

For the controlling:

- Put sensor readings in the sensor classes
- Put motor responses in the motor classes
- Put the control in a special class (Control?) that couples the sensor response to the motor response.